# Define delayed_jobs dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, delayed-job

I am using `delayed_job`s that for some of them have dependencies that need to be executed after the current one and with a small delay. This delay comes from rate limitting of the API I am querying.

**Basic idea**
Here are my jobs constraints:

```
      1s           1s
A1 --------> A2 --------> A3
```

and

```
      1s           1s
B1 --------> B2 --------> B3
```

In the end, I would like this process to take ~2s with something like:

```
           1s              1s
A1 -> B1 -----> B2 -> A2 ------> A3 -> B3
```

or

```
           1s              1s
A1 -> B1 -----> A2 -> B2 ------> A3 -> B3
```

or whatever order which respects my first constraints, but with dependencies and waiting.

**More context**
I am currently building an app for Shopify. An app for Shopify is rate limitted by 2 API calls/s per shop.
But the webhooks coming from shopify that send me jobs to do can be way more than 2 per second per shop so I need to use jobs to handle them.
Then each job actually send two request to their API.

**Considered approach**
I could use a second queue and use the `after` hook to fetch the next job to do for the shop and add it to the jobs table with `run_at: 1.seconds.from_now`. However, I don't really like the idea, because I'll have to store the `perform` arguments in the table instead of just calling a `perform_later` method. Also, I really imagine that this isn't the first use case where dependencies are needed with delayed_job, so I'm sure there is a better approach to it that I just couldn't find.

Any idea would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all clear what you're trying to do, but a good common pattern that has worked for me most of the time (many millions of times with a few exceptions)...

- when you get a webhook call, create the job (if you have not already seen that webhook call), and return 200 status as fast as possible. That keeps Shopify happy and stops them sending you the same hook over again.
- MonkeyPatch ActiveResource to inspect the credit left header number in your App, so that you can easily go into a 500ms wait if the calls left are zero. Works a charm... for 2/second limit.

Comment: I've read such solutions, but I would really love to avoid the `sleep`, because we could handle so much more requests to other shops with one single process during this time.

Comment: Your problem is not in sleeping, but in waiting for API limits. You are not using one thread here to do one thing at a time.

Comment: Whatever the number of thread is, waiting in a thread means that this thread isn't doing anything else. Let's say *client1* adds 1000 products then *client2* adds 1. Whatever the number of workers/threads, with your approach, the *client2* will have to wait until the 1000 of the *client1* are done  (~= 15mins) because all my threads will be sleeping because they each took the jobs for the *client1* first instead of processing jobs they could handle right now. Which is almost like if you were in a mono-threaded environment in fact.

Comment: Oh, did you mean retry the job with a waiting time on it?

Comment: I can't speak for how you architect things, but it does sound like you are having trouble with concerns that exceed my knowledge. I would never worry about the 1 vs 1000 like you. I cannot see assigning a priority to an incoming 1 vs an incoming 1000. To me they all rate the same attention. I only get into priority on the type of job.

Comment: In this example, I only took 1 v 1000 to show that the 1 from *client2* could be executed almost directly because we are bumping into the rate limits of *client1* but instead we have to wait until all jobs of *client1* are done (at that 2req/s slow rate), at least I believe.

Comment: Since you can examine the size of the job. When you get a 1, assign it a higher priority for workers, and peel it off a queue made for quick and dirty... lay the 1000 into a slower queue